# Java update GUI with simulation running

Tags: java, user-interface, bluej

I am trying to make a java simulation of a train moving from station to station. I have the main code working but having trouble with the GUI. I have the basic layout with a start and stop button but as soon as the start button is selected, the main loop runs for the simulation and the GUI doesn't respond. I've been having trouble finding how to work around this. And help wpuld be much appreciated!

Here is the main simulation class:

> /**
>    * Here is the main simulation class that runs the main loop.
>    * It uses instances of two classes  : train and station.
>    * @author Ollie Jones
>    * 
>    */
>   public class SimEngine
>   {

```
/**
 * Station object array and train object initialised.
 * The line has 16 station so an array of 16 is needed.
 */

Station[] station = new Station[16];
Train train = new Train();
int forwardTimeArray[];
int backwardTimeArray[];


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class SimEngine
 */
public SimEngine()
{

    /**
     * Here that values are initialised.
     */
    train = new Train();
    forwardTimeArray = new int[]{1,4,2,4,6,3,3,5,3,2,5,5,1,4,2};
    backwardTimeArray = new int[]{3,2,4,5,2,2,4,3,4,2,5,2,1,4,5};
    // A for loop is used to initialse the station number
    for(int i=0; i<station.length; i++){
        station[i] = new Station();
        station[i].setStationNumber(i+1);
    }

    /**
     * Each station name is initialised separately as
     * they all have different names.
     */
    station[0].setStationName("Name of 1st station");
    station[1].setStationName("Name of 2nd station");
    station[2].setStationName("Name of 3rd station");
    station[3].setStationName("Name of 4th station");
    station[4].setStationName("Name of 5ht station");
    station[5].setStationName("Name of 6th station");
    station[6].setStationName("Name of 7th station");
    station[7].setStationName("Name of 8th station");
    station[8].setStationName("Name of 9th station");
    station[9].setStationName("Name of 10th station");
    station[10].setStationName("Name of 11th station");
    station[11].setStationName("Name of 12th station");
    station[12].setStationName("Name of 13th station");
    station[13].setStationName("Name of 14th station");
    station[14].setStationName("Name of 15th station");
    station[15].setStationName("Name of 16th station");

}

/**
 * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
 *
 * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
 * @return    the sum of x and y
 */

    /**
 * This method stats the train simulation.
 * 
 */
public void start()
{
    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("Station Number:1"); //Print the first staion number.
    while(x == 0){
        int stationNumber = 0;
        int time = 0;
        Boolean forwards;
        stationNumber = train.getStationNumber();
        forwards = train.getDirection();
        if (forwards == true){
            time = forwardTimeArray[stationNumber-1];
            sleep(time);
            stationNumber = stationNumber + 1;
            System.out.println("Station Nubmer:" + stationNumber);
            train.setStationNumber(stationNumber);
        }

        else{
            time = backwardTimeArray[stationNumber-2];
            sleep(time);
            stationNumber = stationNumber - 1;
            System.out.println("Station Number:" + stationNumber);
            train.setStationNumber(stationNumber);
        }
        if (stationNumber == 1){
            forwards = true;
        }
        else if (stationNumber == 16){
            forwards = false;
            //train.setStationNumber(stationNumber-1);

        }
        train.setDirection(forwards);
    }
}
public static void sleep(int time)
{
    try{
        time = time * 100;
        Thread.sleep(time);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
}

public void stop()
{
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Here is the sim class where the simulation is started.

```
public class Sim 
{
    private GUI gui;
    private SimEngine engine;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class sim
     * 
     */
    public Sim()
    {
        engine = new SimEngine();
        gui = new GUI(engine);
    }

    /**
     * Opens window if it has been closed.
     */

    public void show()
    {
        gui.setVisable(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the GUI, where the main issue is (i think).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField display;
    private final SimEngine sim;
    private JLabel infoLabel;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GUI
     */
    public GUI(SimEngine engine)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        makeFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        sim = engine;
    }

    /**
     * Creates GUI frame!
     */
    public void makeFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Train Simulation");

        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,8));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

        display = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        addButton(buttonPanel, "Start", () -> sim.start());
        addButton(buttonPanel, "Stop", () -> sim.stop());

        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private void addButton(Container panel, String buttonText, ButtonAction
            action)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(buttonText);
        button.addActionListener(e -> {action.act(); redisplay(); });
        panel.add(button);
    }

    private interface ButtonAction
    {
        /**
         * act on button press.
         */
        void act();
    }

    private void redisplay()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Makes frame visable.
     */
    public void setVisable(boolean visable){
        frame.setVisible(visable);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not suppose to run long processes on the swing thread ([edt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)) because it blocks it. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). For more help you would need to post [mcve].

Comment: What is a minimal, complete and verifiable example?

Comment: Please follow the link given

Answer (score 1):

You're running your simulation on the event dispatch thread. While your calculations are happening, they are monopolizing the thread that handles UI events, so it can't process anything and the UI freezes.

Use [worker threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

It looks like you have this usecase (from the linked tutorial):

> The background task can provide intermediate results by invoking SwingWorker.publish, causing SwingWorker.process to be invoked from the event dispatch thread.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54969779/3992939) answer, running long processes on the [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) blocks it, so it does not respond to changes. 
One alternative is to use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which does the background processing in its `doInBackground()` method, publishes interim values (`publish` method) and is capable of updating gui (`process` method). 
The following is a basic implementation of a SwingWorker, based on your code. 
It can be copy-pasted into one file (GUI.java) and run.
Note the comments in the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField display;
    private final SimEngine sim;
    private JLabel infoLabel;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GUI
     */
    public GUI(SimEngine engine)
    {
        // initialize instance variables
        makeFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        sim = engine;
    }

    /**
     * Creates GUI frame!
     */
    public void makeFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Train Simulation");

        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,8));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

        display = new JTextField();
        contentPane.add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        addButton(buttonPanel, "Start", () -> sim.start());
        addButton(buttonPanel, "Stop", () -> sim.stop());

        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private void addButton(Container panel, String buttonText, ButtonAction  action)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(buttonText);
        button.addActionListener(e -> {action.act(); redisplay(); });
        panel.add(button);
    }

    void updateDisplay(String newValue){
        display.setText(newValue);
    }

    private interface ButtonAction
    {
        /**
         * act on button press.
         */
        void act();
    }

    private void redisplay() {  }

    /**
     * Makes frame visible.
     */
    public void setVisable(boolean visable){
        frame.setVisible(visable);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sim sim = new Sim();
        sim.show();
    }
}

//implements Listener so it can listen to SimEngine value changes 
class Sim  implements Listener
{
    private final GUI gui;
    private final SimEngine engine;


    public Sim()
    {
        engine = new SimEngine(this);
        gui = new GUI(engine);
    }

    /**
     * make gui visible 
     */
    public void show()
    {
        gui.setVisable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(String newValue){
        gui.updateDisplay(newValue);
    }
}

class SimEngine {

    /**
     * Station object array and train object initialized.
     * The line has 16 station so an array of 16 is needed.
     */
    private final Station[] station = new Station[16];
    private Train train = new Train();
    private final int forwardTimeArray[],  backwardTimeArray[];
    private final Listener listener;

    //accept a listener 
    public SimEngine(Listener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
        train = new Train();
        forwardTimeArray = new int[] {1,4,2,4,6,3,3,5,3,2,5,5,1,4,2,3}; //needs 16 values, had only 16
        backwardTimeArray = new int[]{3,2,4,5,2,2,4,3,4,2,5,2,1,4,5,4};
        // A for loop is used to initialize the station number and name
        for(int i=0; i<station.length; i++){
            station[i] = new Station();
            station[i].setStationNumber(i+1);
            station[0].setStationName("Station #"+(i+1));
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method starts the train simulation.
     *
     */
    public void start()
    {
        //have all background processing done by a SwingWorker so GUI does not freeze
        new SimulationWorker().execute();
    }
    public static void sleep(int time)
    {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(time * 300);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    class SimulationWorker extends SwingWorker<Void,Integer>{

        boolean stop = false; //use if you wish to stop 

        //do background processing 
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while(! stop){
                int stationNumber = 0;
                int time = 0;
                boolean forwards;
                stationNumber = train.getStationNumber();

                forwards = train.getDirection();
                if (stationNumber == 1){
                    forwards = true;
                    train.setDirection(forwards);
                }
                else if (stationNumber == 15){
                    forwards = false;
                    train.setDirection(forwards);
                }

                if (forwards == true){
                    time = forwardTimeArray[stationNumber+1];//time = forwardTimeArray[stationNumber-1];
                    sleep(time);
                    stationNumber = stationNumber + 1;
                    //System.out.println("Station Number:" + stationNumber);
                    train.setStationNumber(stationNumber);
                }
                else{
                    time = backwardTimeArray[stationNumber-2];
                    sleep(time);
                    stationNumber = stationNumber - 1;
                    //System.out.println("Station Number:" + stationNumber);
                    train.setStationNumber(stationNumber);
                }
                publish(train.getStationNumber()); //publish result (station number)
            }
            return null;
        }

        //process published information 
        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> stationsList) {
            for(int stationNumber : stationsList){
                listener.valueChanged("Train is at "+ stationNumber); //notify listener 
            }
        }
    }
}

class Train {

    private  int stationNumber = 0;
    private  boolean forwards = true ;

    public int getStationNumber() {
        return stationNumber;
    }

    public void setDirection(boolean forwards) {
        this.forwards = forwards;
    }

    public void setStationNumber(int stationNumber) {
        this.stationNumber = stationNumber;
    }

    public boolean getDirection() {
        return forwards;
    }
}

class Station {

    private int stationNumber;
    private String stationName;

    public void setStationNumber(int stationNumber) {
        this.stationNumber = stationNumber;
    }

    public void setStationName(String stationName) {
        this.stationName = stationName;
    }
}

//an interface use by Sim to listen to SimEngine changes 
interface Listener {
    void valueChanged(String newValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have tried to do this but in the SimulationWorker the variables like train and forwardTimeArray are not recignised. Do I have to make getters and setters for these in the SimEngine class?

Comment: I am using blueJ if that makes a difference?

Comment: The code posted runs with no problem. Copy paste the entire code into one file (GUI.java) and run.

Comment: I am using blueJ which doen't alow me to put all the code into one file, is there another program you would reccomend?

Comment: You do not have to put it all in one file. I offered that for your convenience. I am not familiar with blueJ but I don't see why you can not create a GUI.java file, add the package name, and paste all the code after it.

Comment: I have tride this but get multiple errors in the SimulationWorker class. All the get methods no longer work for the train intsance and also values from the forward and backward timeArrays can't be found. It also says "method does not override or impliment a method from super type. The exectue method in SimEngine also cant be found.

Comment: My answer does not include `execute` method. If you get this error I assume you mix your code with mine. Put my code in a separate package and try.